# Change the order how ggplot draws border colors in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(Taxon=c("A", "B", "C"),
                 Counts=c(0.1,0.5,0.4),
                 Treatment=rep("X1",3),
                 Effect=factor(c("A","B","A")))
df$Effect <- factor(df$Effect, levels=c("A","B"), ordered=T)

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=df, aes(x = Treatment, y = Counts, fill = Taxon, colour=Effect), 
           stat="identity", position="fill", width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual("",values=c("gold", "green","yellow"))+
  scale_color_manual("",values=c("black","red"))
```

i want to highlight the effect "B" with a red border around all "Taxon" of that effect type. But ggplot seems to draw the rectangles in sequential order of `df$Taxon`, and not as i would wish by first applying the color assigned to df$Effect == A, then df$Effect == B. The same is true when changing the order of df$Effect.

```
df$Effect <- factor(df$Effect, levels=c("B","A"), ordered=T)


ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=df, aes(x = Treatment, y = Counts, fill = Taxon, colour=Effect), 
           stat="identity", position="fill", width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual("",values=c("gold", "green","yellow"))+
  scale_color_manual("",values=c("black","red"))
```

How to code this when i want to always have complete red rectangles around taxons expressing the effect "B"?

Comment: `scale_*_manual` functions accept `values` parameters that are either named or unnamed, so you could use `values = c(A = "black", B = "red")` or however you need it setup